# Assign backbone URL based on promise value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, promise

I'm trying to refactor some 'synchronous' ajax code (that uses async:false to grab some config properties from a json file and return them). I removed the `async:false`s and am now returning a promise that resolves with the value.

Some of the return values are URLs that need to be used as the URL properties for backbone models and collections. So the function (in Config.js) was previously

```
getUrl: function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'config.json',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
           this.applicationUrl = response.applicationUrl;
        }
    });
    return this.applicationUrl;
}
```

Then in the URL property of a collection or model, it has:

```
url: function () {
    return Config.getUrl();
}
```

So the way I tried to get around this is by having the getURL function return a promise, like so:

```
getUrl: function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    if (this.applicationUrl) {
        deferred.resolve(this.applicationUrl);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'config.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
               this.applicationUrl = response.applicationUrl;
               deferred.resolve(this.applicationUrl);
            }
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

and then in the initialize method of the model/collection, I call:

```
initialize: function () {
    Config.getUrl().done(function (url) {
        this.baseUrl = url;
    });
},
url: function () {
    return this.baseUrl;
}
```

But is there any way to ensure that the promise is resolved before the url needs to get used for a fetch?

Comment: Why not create model on config resolve?

Comment: There are lots of different types of models that depend on the property that Config is returning. It's actually checking if the property is set, grabbing it via ajax if not, or resolving it immediately if so. The getUrl method is used all over the place for different models.

Comment: What property? In your snippet ajax is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1376) that Backbone doesn't handle promises for `url`.

Here I'm assigning the promise function to a property on the model, and checking the state on the sync method to make sure it's resolved first.

```
initialize: function () {
    this._getUrl = Config.getUrl();

    this._getUrl.done(function (url) {
       this.url = url;
    }.bind(this));
},

sync: function(method, model, options) {
    options || (options = {});

    if (this._getUrl.state() === 'pending') {
     return this._getUrl.done(function (url) {
       options.url = url;

       return sync();
     }.bind(this));
    } else {
      return sync();
    }

    function sync() {
      return Backbone.sync.call(model, method, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: But there's no guarantee that the 'done' function will complete before fetch/sync - right?

Comment: @thisAnneM good point. Maybe you can check the status of the promise in the `sync` method and wait for it before syncing.